# Iam trying to install cocoapi but iam getting this error

Tags: python-3.x, object, detection

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\sangay  sherpa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Error parsing requirements for tensorflow-gpu: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\sangay  sherpa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_gpu-2.1.0.dist-info\METADATA'

Answer (score 0):

You can find some problems in your folder[c:\users\sangay sherpa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages],There have some error packet such as the [ip],this packet maybe become ~ip.
like this packet_img
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQOZc.png)

You can del these packets or make a folder to store them.